# Date and Time function formatting

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create a new function named **dateWriter** with three basic parameters that is "year", "month" and "day" which eventually returns the new date.

Here is what I have:

```js
function dateWriter(year, month, day) {
  return;
}
console.log(dateWriter(2020, 1, 25));
```

I'm not at all sure what to return inside the body, or how to get it into date format.

Thanks!

Comment: First Learn about JS date object and try( https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function dateWriter(year, month, day) {
  return day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
}
console.log(dateWriter(2020, 1, 25));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date(year, month, date)` constructor to create date object. Since integer value representing the month, beginning with `0` for January to `11` for December. Hence you need to subtract `1` from your `month`.

```js
function dateWriter(year, month, day) {
  return new Date(year, month-1, day);;
}
console.log(dateWriter(2020, 1, 25));
```

Comment: This is ok, but not quite what I want. I should have instructed you to leave off the time. Thanks.

Comment: @KingdomB Then mention what you want in the question.

Comment: @Santhosh I did! I said date. Lol

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a new date object with passed in values and return the same.

```js
function dateWriter(year, month, day) {
  return new Date(year, month-1, day);
}
console.log(dateWriter(2020, 1, 25));
```

If you would like to read more about the Date object in JS, the following link will help you : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: what is the difference between your answer with Sudhir answer?

Comment: @Santhosh Well, coincidentally it's same.

Comment: This has the time stamp. I should have mentioned that it wasn't desirable. Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know about up voting.

Answer (score 0):

So what it looks like your question is asking is for you to write a function that returns a date object from parameters. Lucky for you, that is pretty easy!

In JavaScript, when creating an object from a constructor function, you use the “new” keyword. The date object is one such object created like that, so you could write

```js
return new Date(year, month-1, day)
```

In the body of the function to return a new date object, constructed with your parameters

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It was easy, I'm embarrassed.